# Javascript changing h1 size/color/etc

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript but have been trudging along. I am stuck now though. I am trying to get my header to shrink when the user scrolls down the page. I have gotten everything to work, except I can't figure out how to get javascript to resize just this one h1 (logo) element. Please help!!

my javascript:

```
var header, yPos;
function yScroll(){
header = document.getElementById('header');
yPos = window.pageYOffset;
if(yPos > 120){
    header.style.height = "36px";
    header.style.paddingTop = "0px";
    header.style.background = "#005A31";
} else {
    header.style.height = "120px";
    header.style.paddingTop = "10px";
    header.style.background = "#A8CD1B";
}
}
```

my HTML:

```
<div class = "container" id = "header">
STUFF HERE
<div class = "container" id = "logo">
<h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
    </div>
STUFF HERE
 </div>
```

Comment: did you bind the event to window?

Comment: This code should work if invoked. Do you have a picture in your logo?

Comment: the code is working, but i am trying to find a way to change the size of my h1 element with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, everything is fine but you need to bind the function to document.

You can do as followed

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", yScroll);
```

Edit: For the size of text, you need to change font-size property. You're changing height which is the height of area.

You can do as followed:

First add h1 an id.

```
<h1 id="myH" ...
```

then

```
document.getElementById("myH").style.fontSize = "36px";
```

Comment: everything is working fine right now, however i can't find out how to change the size of my h1 element. that is what i'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have tried add header.style.fontSize but that only changes plain text inside of the header, it doesn't change the size of my h1 element inside of the header.